# Style not applied on button in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this style in the ContentPage I'm working on:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="EndAndExpand"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

and applied it on a button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="New user" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"/>
```

What I want to accomplish is something like this (drawn in MS Paint):
[image]

But that's what I get (from Android emulator):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me.

Please try uninstalling the App and delete bin and obj folder then rebuild and deploy.